# .NET getting the Now property cost

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance

Useless question I guess, but accessing the property `DateAndTime.Now` computes each time the current system date and time, I suppose, is that right?

Thus it would be just a liiiiiittle better to favor:

```
Dim rightNow As Date = Now
For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
    If expiration < rightNow Then
        '   ...
    End If
Next
```

Over

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
    If expiration < Now() Then
        '   ...
    End If
Next
```

Am I right?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?  In the first example it will either always take or not take the true part of the conditional, assuming expiration is not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime.Now does a lot of processing:

```
public static DateTime Now
{
  get
  {
        DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        bool isAmbiguousDst = false;
        long ticks = TimeZoneInfo.GetDateTimeNowUtcOffsetFromUtc(utcNow, 
              out isAmbiguousDst).Ticks;
        long num = utcNow.Ticks + ticks;
        if (num > 3155378975999999999L)
        {
              return new DateTime(3155378975999999999L, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
        if (num < 0L)
        {
              return new DateTime(0L, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }
        return new DateTime(num, DateTimeKind.Local, isAmbiguousDst);
  }
}
```

It converts the utcNow to your local time. Because of the this calling is expensive. Depending on your requirements, the first sample will give you better performance.

Comment: If you were looking for the source code for this function, please ask for that in your original question.

Answer (score 4):

You would be correct, you'd only want to make the Now() call as often as needed.

Comment: Assuming that you want the same value. If you need an up to date value, of course, you need to get now() each time. It all depends what happens in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you want to achieve.

If you require all iterations to use the *most accurate* time, then Option 1 is the way to go.

If you require all iterations to use the *same* time, then Option 2 is the way to go.

I wouldn't worry too much about the performance of calling DateTime.Now, unless you have already confirmed that it makes a difference for your application. Making sure your program behaves *correctly* is more important.

Comment: yes, I wrote "useless question" just because it's not a real performance problem even in a 1 million iterations loop, I think. I'd like to see the Now code though.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to test. Here are the average timings on my computer:

```
00:00:00.0000260

00:00:00.0015428
```

Is that a meaningful difference? Only you know if it is for your application. And as others have pointed out, how accurate do you need `Now()` to be?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, however rightnow won't be rightnow as soon as you've done the assignment...if you get my drift.

I'd be interested in seeing some timings to see how much of a difference there is between the two methods.